# Could some one perform an OCR on this image successfully?

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, neural-network, ocr

I've tried with some demo downloaded from the web to test an OCR on this image, the characters on image are not well-formed as printing characters you can see when you type in a TextBox. I'm not experienced enough about OCR and Neural Network. These are my images https://sites.google.com/site/thecabinet3/home/files-store/sample.bmp?attredirects=0 and https://sites.google.com/site/thecabinet3/home/files-store/6bi.bmp?attredirects=0

I have some questions here:

1. Do I have to re-train the neural network with these new non-standard characters, the network has already been trained using a standard character set. (I mean the standard character looks like character you see when typing any character with a specified font into a TextBox).
2. Could you perform an OCR on the images I uploaded successfully using some example? If you could, please give me that working example?

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I tested your image in a commercial high-quality webservice OCR and received 100% recognition result out of box.
65 -HC
0999

I looked at your sample, and in my experience it has enough quality and character definition to produce high quality result in any descent OCR system, unless your algorithm is very sensitive to rough edges of character patterns.

I am not sure if your need is academic or commercial.  Last time I used neural networks for OCR was very many years ago in college, but not in commercial implementations due to training limitations.

Comment: Thank you, my need is just academic, I've tried with some open source libraries such as Tesseract, vietocr but they couldn't recognize the characters. I've also tried with Accord.NET and it seems to work OK if I supply much enough training data. I think the webservice you suggested has a high quality enough to recognize the characters in my image. However I just like free stuff.